# Auto resize a scrollview with swift in all devices

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I trying create an application to see in iPhone 5, iPhone 6 and Plus, but my code was programmed manually, how will i it make, please help me, i don't know whats is wrong. I trying add autolayouts but manually,

My code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    override func loadView() {
        // calling self.view later on will return a UIView!, but we can simply call
        // self.scrollView to adjust properties of the scroll view:
        self.view = self.scrollView

        // setup the scroll view
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:1534, height: 5678)
        // etc...
    }

    func example() {
        let sampleSubView = UIView()
        self.view.addSubview(sampleSubView) // adds to the scroll view

        // cannot do this:
        // self.view.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)
        // so instead we do this:
        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        var value:CGFloat = 89.0
        var total = 10
        for var index = 0; index < total; ++index {
            //View  verde
            var DynamicView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, value, 375, 198))
            DynamicView.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
            scrollView.addSubview(DynamicView)

            //Imagenn Fondo  rojo
            var fondo :UIImageView
            fondo = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 198))
            fondo.image = UIImage(named:"catedral.jpg")
            fondo.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
            DynamicView.addSubview(fondo)

            //Labels Nombre y Dirección texto blanco
            var nombreLabel=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8,y: 23,width: 304,height: 21))
            nombreLabel.text="Nombre Negocio"
            nombreLabel.font = UIFont(name: nombreLabel.font.fontName, size: 20)
            nombreLabel.textColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
            DynamicView.addSubview(nombreLabel)
            var direccionLabel=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 8,y: 44,width: 304,height: 21))
            direccionLabel.text="Dirección Negocio"
            direccionLabel.font = UIFont(name: nombreLabel.font.fontName, size: 13)
            direccionLabel.textColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
            DynamicView.addSubview(direccionLabel)

            //Puntuación  gris
            var puntuacion :UIImageView
            puntuacion = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(340, 8, 30, 30))
            //puntuacion.image = UIImage(named:"7")
            puntuacion.backgroundColor=UIColor.grayColor()
            DynamicView.addSubview(puntuacion)

            //Botones  blanco
            var button1:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(8, 114, 32, 32))
            button1.addTarget(self, action: "button1:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            button1.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
            DynamicView.addSubview(button1)
            button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "marker"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            var button2:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(48, 114, 32, 32))
            button2.addTarget(self, action: "button2:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            button2.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
            DynamicView.addSubview(button2)
            button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "marker"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            var button3:UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(88, 114, 32, 32))
            button3.addTarget(self, action: "button3:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            button3.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
            DynamicView.addSubview(button3)
            button3.setImage(UIImage(named: "marker"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            //Cenefa Info  gris
            var cenefa :UIImageView
            cenefa = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 150, 375, 48))
            cenefa.backgroundColor=UIColor.grayColor()
            cenefa.alpha=1
            DynamicView.addSubview(cenefa)

            //Info Ccenefa  amarillo
            var descripcion=UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 2,y: 0,width: 370,height: 45))
            descripcion.backgroundColor=UIColor.yellowColor()
            descripcion.text="Descripcion Negocio"
            descripcion.font = UIFont(name: nombreLabel.font.fontName, size: 10)
            descripcion.textColor=UIColor.blueColor()
            cenefa.addSubview(descripcion)

            value=value+200.0

        }
        scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, 2089)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe in your question what you expect to see and what you actually see in your code?

Comment: I trying add a autolayouts manually.